# Install shield 2011 installscript functions

Tags: windows-installer, installation, installshield

How to disable some of the existing functions under install script. My install script is having too many functions that, I don't want for minor upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level, you can find the function that calls it, and replace that function. Use the dropdown at the top to select a function, and it will insert the current code, allowing you to modify it. This approach, other than the dropdown part, includes the top-level `program`/`endprogram` block in theory. (I would not suggest replacing that, especially in an InstallScript MSI.)

I believe the entry points you would want to examine for altering the behavior of a minor upgrade are `OnResumeUIBefore` and `OnResumeUIAfter`.